# How to center the lists inside the ul in fluid layout?

Tags: html, css

The html

```
<div class="wrapContent">
   <ul>
      <li>Lorem</li>
      <li>Lorem</li>
      <li>Lorem</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

.wrapper is a fluid div, I am trying to center the floated left lists on the page. Basically be able to have same distances left/right for the first and last li in the ul.

Currently I do:

```
.wrapContent {
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0 auto;
}

.ul {
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0 auto;
}

.li {
   width: 250px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't float them.  (That's kind of an important detail you should've included in your question...  :))  Use `display` instead.

```
ul {
    text-align: center;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;  /* optional */
}
```

Now the `li`s will each *act like* inline elements, but preserve the structure of their contents, and you can center them like anything else.

By the way, you don't need to use `width: 100%;` on block elements; they automatically expand to fit the width of their container.

Comment: mm the second row would have the lis centered tho

Comment: what?  you mean if they wrap, the first line will be longer than the second?  off the top of my head i don't think you can avoid that.

Comment: yes preceisly... i guess the only solution is to have multple uls for each row